# In javascript, is array = [] equal to array = [[]]? If not, why this behavior?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I have this function:

```
function addToArray() {
  var thesesArrays = []; // an empty array
  var sometheses = ["With I/O Speech, Larry Page Reminds Us Why Google Rules Tech", "Tech", "myID_xGr52srsiwi"];
  thesesArrays.push(sometheses); // the empty array gains one array
  Logger.log("thesesArrays[0][1] = " + thesesArrays[0]);  
  Logger.log("thesesArrays = " + thesesArrays); 
}
```

I'm new to JS programming (and programming in general), so it can seems like a very newbie question. Why the logs of `thesesArrays[0][1]` and `thesesArrays` are identical?

[image]

The `thesesArrays` logs should not be something like this: `[["With I/O Speech, Larry Page Reminds Us Why Google Rules Tech", "Tech", "myID_xGr52srsiwi"]]`?

Comment: The latter is a multidimensional array.  It's an array within an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding of how they should be is correct.

In JavaScript, objects that extend the native Object type have a `toString()` method which is intended to represent that instance as a `String`. It just so happens that when you call `toString()` on an Array you get all the `toString()` values of the array's elements with a comma placed between them.

In your first call to `Logger.log()`, you pass it what is represented in memory as this:

```
["With I/O Speech, Larry Page Reminds Us Why Google Rules Tech", "Tech", "myID_xGr52srsiwi"]
```

If you call `toString()` on this Array, you get the string:

```
"With I/O Speech, Larry Page Reminds Us Why Google Rules Tech,Tech,myID_xGr52srsiwi"
```

Which is the results of calling `toString()` on all the elements (which return themselves because they **are** strings), and then adding `,`s in between.

In your second call, you provide the containing array `thesesArrays`. The same logic applies here in that it recursively follows the same logic as described above, but because the `Array` only has one element in it (which is an `Array` itself), no separating commas are needed.

To prove this, let's add another Array to the parent array `thesesArrays`:

```
thesesArrays.push('my second array'.split(' '))
```

Now if you call `toString()` on `thesesArrays` you'll see that our new array has been added to the end, separated by commas:

```
"With I/O Speech, Larry Page Reminds Us Why Google Rules Tech,Tech,myID_xGr52srsiwi,my,second,array"
```

**For reference:**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString

Answer (score 1):

The arrays are not equal. 
[Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kvesJ). In my example if you view the javascript console, you will see one logs an Array[1] of one array. And the other logs an Array[3] of 3 strings.

It appears you are casting the arrays to strings when you add them to the pre-existing string in the log. Those two arrays casted to strings are identical.

Comment: His question has the `google-apps-script` tag. The `Logger` is one of the standard classes: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/logger

Comment: The documentation doesn't go into detail about how `Logger` formats the data. From the example in the question, it appears that it doesn't display the object's structure, it just finds the strings in it and displays them.

Comment: It doesn't depend on the way logger logs but how `+` works for a string and an array.

Answer (score 1):

The arrays are not the same, however, the string representation of them is. When an Array is converted to a String in Javascript, the '[' and ']' are (counter-intuitively) not included.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString

Answer (score 0):

You are not comparing `theseArrays[0]` with `theseArrays` but rather, you look at strings that are output in your logger. Strings were created by prepending some labels to objects.

This is not a reliable way of comparing objects. Try comparision operators at least and you'll find that objects are different.

The issue stems from the fact that `+` tries to be smart and if you are adding string to an array, Javascript converts the array to a string:

```
var tab = ["a", "b"];

console.log( tab );
console.log( "a" + tab );
```

outputs

```
["a", "b"]
aa,b
```